# Prevent direct access to a webpage by typing the URL

Tags: php, html, apache

So I'm hosting my website (let's call is **abc.com**) on goDaddy.

I have a login page (**abc.com/login.html**).

Which takes me to a second page called booking (*abc.com/booking.html*) once the login credentials are verified.

So I don't want people to be able to just type **abc.com/booking.html** and access it. I want them to go to **abc.com/login.html** and then go to **abc.com/booking.html**

So I came across 2 ways to fix this -

1. Include a validating php script in booking.html and changing the extension from html to phtml. -> This didn't work for me
2. Include a .htacess file. -> I'm not really sure how to do that

Comment: you may need the `$_SESSION` for the prevention.

Comment: You need to do something server side. The .htaccess file would kind of replace your login page, I don't think you want that.
So, as the others said, you need to do something with PHP or another server language (node.js, Java, ... I don't know which of them are available on goDaddy).
The concept is to give a user a session id after he has logged in. This session id could be for example stored in a cookie or somwhere. When the user accesses a page, the script checks the session id. Only if the id is valid, the user may continue.

Comment: Remeber `$_SESSION` run `PHP` not `HTML`.

Comment: let me know if my answer worked for you

Comment: You server might not support `phtml` - mine doesn't. Try `php`, or take a look at your server config to ensure that the extension is  going through PHP correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so your login screen should already have session code implemented into it that has a variable that specifies if the user is logged in or not. If you don't have that implemented yet, the code would look similar to:

```
<?php session_start();//at the very top of the page
?>
//... your own code
//if the user successfully logs in then:
$_SESSION['authenticated']=true;
```

Then on the booking.php page (it should be php to allow php scripts which is super important for validating if a user is logged in), you would then check if the user did log in. If he did, the rest of the page loads, if he didn't, you would redirect them to login.php:

at the very top of booking.php:

```
<?php session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['authenticated']))
{
    //if the value was not set, you redirect the user to your login page
    header('Location https://www.example.com/login.php');
    exit;
}
else
{
   //if the user did login, then you load the page normally
}
```

Comment: @kalpitha No problem :). Oh and if this answer worked for you, please accept it (with a green check mark) so that future users and readers know it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use $_SESSION or
2. Pass a variable from login.php to booking.php. And then authenticate every user based on the variable passed using the $_POST method.

eg.

```
if (!isset($_POST['auth'])) {
 // redirect user back to login page
} else {
 // successful login
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

rename extensions of all pages where you want this authentification

e.g.

```
login.html >> login.php
booking.html >> booking.php
booking-suceess.html >> booking-success.php
```

create one script namely **auth.php** with following code

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("location:login.php");
}
?>
```

In **login.php** add session

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

Now you can add **auth.php** in any php page where you want login compulsory as follow :

```
include ('auth.php');
```