# How do I prevent people from accessing a page on my site with just the URL?

Tags: html, wordpress

**How can I do block a site page from the outside? I don't want anyone accessing a the page without going through another one first. For example, I don't someone to just be able to type www.example.com/test without first being on www.example.com and then pressing a link I have pasted on the www.example.com.** I have seen another question similar, but I don't know anything about coding so the answers are confusing for me. Could someone direct me in the way to do? This was the post I saw, but I don't understand the answers: [Prevent direct access to a webpage by typing the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509969/prevent-direct-access-to-a-webpage-by-typing-the-url). I don't want anyone, even logged in users to be able to access these pages, at least not until they have paid, but that is another story. However, if you could help me with that, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think WordPress has a plugin for this so you'll have to get into the code.  I also don't know what language WordPress uses but if your file extensions are .html, .htm, or .php then you're in business.  There are a few ways you can do this but I'm going to give you the way that should be compatible with all browsers.

So on your referrer page (in your case example.com) you're going to insert the following code between `<head>` and `</head>`:

```
<script>
  function redirect(){
    document.getElementById('redirect').submit();
  }
</script>
```

Then, on the same page between `<body>` and `</body>` insert:

```
<form id='redirect' action='/yourPage' method='POST'>
  <input type='hidden' name='redirected', value='true' hidden>
</form>
```

Make sure to change yourPage to the correct page. Next, on the same page between `<body>` and `</body>` find something that looks like:

```
<a href='/yourPage'>What ever your link says</a>
```

And change it to:

```
<a href='javascript:redirect()'>What ever you want your link to say</a>
```

Lastly, go to the page you want protected (you wrote it as test, it's yourPage in my code) and first, make sure the if the extension is .html or .htm, change it to .php, then insert the following at the very top:

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_SERVER['POST']['redirected'])){
    header('Location:www.example.com');
    die();
  }
?>
```

Make sure to change www.example.com to your website.  You may also wonder what the 'die()' does.  The 'header' part is a redirect REQUEST and will all requests, the client can say no.  So die basically says if you don't redirect, you still can't see the web page.

Hopefully this helps, if your page is not .htm, .html, or .php please comment what the extension is so I can find an equivalent in that language.

Comment: I think it is php. Do you know where can I go to edit the page code?

Comment: @eliza You'll have to find the source code for your WordPress site, this will be where ever you Apache Server is installed, it's different for every operating system.